# How would you take the derivative of this function?

Tags: calculus, summation

$$f(x)=\sum_{i=1}^x\frac1i$$
$$f'(x)=?$$
NOTE: I am defining f(x) for all natural number and considering the function as you zoom out

Is it even possible to take this derivative? Why or why not? If so, what meaning does the derivative convey? What function does f(x) approach as you zoom out? These are all questions that popped into my head when considering this function and now I look to you to answer them because my small brain can not.

Comment: What does it even mean to have $x$ as the end of a summation, if $x$ isn't a natural number?

Comment: Well, for this I am assuming x is a natural number and I am considering the function as you zoom out

Comment: It doesn't make sense. I wouldn't put more thought on it.

Comment: Then what does the derivative mean on a function that inputs natural numbers?

Comment: I am asking the question, not answering it

Comment: Does [THIS](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0377042704003851) help?

Comment: There is a notion of the derivative of an integer and so-called arithmetic functions - see [Arithmetic derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_derivative) - but it's not for me to know whether that's entirely relevant for this question.

Comment: @jjagmath  [THIS](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0377042704003851) shows that it does make sense as others have "put more thought into it." ;-))

Comment: @MarkViola umm... for such a simple expression there are simpler extensions of it; no need to think too hard. See my answer.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel I was addressing the topic in general, not this specific case. Capisce?

Comment: @MarkViola OK, at least that (the generalised summation paper) is interesting to know. $\ddot\smile$

Comment: Existence of derivative $f'(a)$ requires $f(x)$ to be defined in some interval $(a,b)$  or $(b,a)$. Definition $f(n)=\sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac1{i}$ does not define values of function in interval. That's why there is not enough data. For example, one can take $f(x)=f(\lfloor x\rfloor)+(x-\lfloor x\rfloor)(f(\lfloor x\rfloor+1)-f(\lfloor x\rfloor))$. Then $f'(x)=f(\lfloor x\rfloor+1)-f(\lfloor x\rfloor)$ for any non-integer $x$. One can take also $f(x)=f(\lfloor x\rfloor)$. Then $f'(x)=0$ for any non-integer $x$.

Comment: A function must have a "dense" domain in order for the derivative to even make sense.

Comment: @MarkViola:  the paper you cite is just "re-proposing" the concept of *Indefinite Sum* which is well established since long: see Wiki link in my answer or the dedicated chapter in the renowned work *"Concrete Mathematics"*

Comment: @GCab I never claimed that this was a recent publicatoin.  In fact, the paper was from 2005.  Aside, the content therein introduced a general approch to defining $F(X)= \sum_{x=1}^X f(x)$ for any $X\in \mathbb{C}$.  This was NOT simply "re-proposing" as you claimed.  Have a look at the References 6 to the Wiki article you mentioned.   The author is Markus Mueller, the same as the author of the article I referneced!

Comment: @MarkViola: I see ! well, the intention of my comment was not polemic, it was just to hint that the definition  as "anti-Delta" is the most straightforward (..IMO).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might interest you to know that the premise for what you are attempting to do, for a general $f(i)$ not just
for the particular case of $f(i)=\frac{1}{i}$, goes under the name of
[Indefinite_Sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indefinite_sum)
or "Anti-Delta"..

In your particular case, since the [Digamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function)
satisfies the functional identity
$$
\Delta _x \psi (x) = \psi (x + 1) - \psi (x) = \frac{1}{x}
$$
then
$$
\sum\limits_x {\frac{1}{x}}  = \Delta _x ^{ - 1} \left( {\frac{1}{x}} \right) = \psi (x)
$$

Therefore
$$
f(x) = \sum\limits_{k = 1}^x {\frac{1}{k}}  = \sum\nolimits_{k = 1}^{x + 1} {\frac{1}{k}}  = \psi (x + 1) - \psi (1)
$$

note that the second sum is the correct translation of the first under the definition of the indefinite sum,
when this is made "definite".

Consequently
$$
f'(x) = \psi ^{\left( 1 \right)} (x + 1)
$$

Answer (score 5):

$f(x)$ has a natural extension to complex $x$ as the *harmonic number function*
$$H(x)=\psi(x+1)+\gamma$$
Here $\psi$ is the digamma function. It follows that
$$H'(x)=\psi^{(1)}(x+1)$$
with a *trigamma* function.

Comment: What is exact definition of the digamma function? I have seen many people use it,but they just talk about the properties of it

Comment: @SamuelMorrison Look it up on Wikipedia, won't you?

Comment: sry for asking that question